# Simulation: One large simulation or average over multiple smaller simulations

Tags: simulation, clinical-trials

I'm interested in clinical trial simulation. Consider a trial where group `n` receives placebo and group `m` receives treatment. From the literature, I take the relationship

$$ \frac{n \cdot m}{n + m} = \frac{(z_{1-\alpha/2} + z_{1-\beta})^2}{(\delta/\sigma)^2} $$

where `n` and `m` are the number of participants in the groups, $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the significance quantile, $z_{1-\beta}$ is the power quantile, $\delta$ is the difference in treatment effect compared to placebo and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the response.

The simulation allows me to find estimates for $\delta$ and $\sigma$, assuming I have a model for the dose-response-relationship. Now I want to run the simulation for different values of $n$ and $m$ until I satisfy my $\beta$ requirement. For a reliable result, should I run multiple simulations at smaller values of $n$ and $m$ and average over $\delta$ or rather one big simulation with larger $n$ and $m$?

Comment: As I understand your question, you are planning a limited role for simulation in this matter, such that simulation will be used *only* to derive estimates of $\delta$ and $\sigma$ from your model of the drug effect. But why not go all out, simulating *the trial itself* all the way through to the individual-level outcomes for the $n+m$ subjects, the tabulated outcomes and the reported p-value? Simulation is cheap and fun; clinical trials are expensive! To paraphrase a great man: *Do you really want to do a \$100 power analysis on a \$10M trial?*

Comment: Who said that? You mean, repeated simulation of the dose response per patient? The model does actually simulate at patient level, so i guess i have that

Comment: I recently learned, if i run one simulation with large n+m, this is rather a better estimate for the parameters of the model, smaller repeated simulations are better estimates of the dose response.

Comment: As to who the 'great man' is, I have the quote only second-hand. So let me balk at identifying the source. It would certainly help answering your Q if you posted your simulation code. From what I gather so far, however, you might do well to take just 1 lesson from your equation, namely that minimum $n+m$ (i.e., minimum *cost* for the trial) for any fixed parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\delta$, $\sigma$ will be had where $n=m$. Now, forget the equation and simulate balanced trials for different values of $n+m$ and fixed $\alpha$. Find the $n+m$ where $1-\beta$ crosses your threshold.

Comment: The code is live at github (too large to post here with the complete package) but you're very welcome to check it out: https://github.com/mzhKU/Clinical-Trial-Simulator

Comment: +1 for publicly accessible code. You might consider hosting your Shiny app on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io) and including the URL in your question to make it easy for people to access. One thing that could be nice would be 'rugs' in your density plots to illustrate that there are individual trial subjects underneath (what I take to be) the kernel density estimates you're plotting, and that finite-sample properties are of essential importance. Would also be nice to see the underlying dose-response models exposed (perhaps graphically) in full view.

Comment: Sure https://mzhku.shinyapps.io/trialsim/